# How to hide scroll bar on certain pages except for page 1?

Tags: python, tkinter

So I have code for a scroll bar here:

```
master = tk.Tk()
master.geometry("200x200")

scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(master)
scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
text = tk.Text(master, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
text.insert("1.0", "Hello")

text.pack()

text.configure(state="disabled", highlightthickness=0)
scrollbar.config(command=text.yview)
master.mainloop()
```

And the scrollbar works, however it pops up on every single page in my program. I have a program with several pages and classes, and I would like the scrollbar to pop up when clicking a button that leads to that specific page with the scrollbar. The scrollbar keeps poping up on all pages, including the homepage, and I can't find a way to hide it.

This is the page I would like to put the `scrollbar` on:

```
class CookiesBiscuits(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Ingredients", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        backButton = tk.Button(self, text="Back",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        backButton.pack()

        #scrollbar

        master = tk.Tk()
        master.geometry("200x200")

        scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(master)
        scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        text = tk.Text(master, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        text.insert("1.0", "Hello")
        text.pack()

        text.configure(state="disabled", highlightthickness=0)
        scrollbar.config(command=text.yview)
        master.mainloop()
```

If anyone has a way that will let me hide the scrollbar, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with creating a second root window and calling `mainloop` a second time? You cannot write tkinter programs this way. If you need another window then you need to create an instance of `Toplevel`, not `Tk`, and you must only call `mainloop` once.

Comment: I don't necessarily need the window. Is there a way to hide it on Tk without the window?

Comment: If you don't need it, why are you creating it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you copied was designed for each page to be a standalone object. All widgets within a page are managed by the page.

If you want a page to have scrollbars and a text widget, those widgets need to have the page as the parent:

```
scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self)
scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
text = tk.Text(self, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
```

You also need to remove the following statements, since in the comments you implied you don't actually want or need another window (plus there's the fact that creating a second instance of `Tk` and calling `mainloop` a second time is not something you should do in general)

```
master = tk.Tk()
master.geometry("200x200")
master.mainloop()
```